# how to fetch data from nested Json object in angular4-Ngrx-lodash

Tags: json, angular, typescript, lodash, ngrx

I am trying to display dropdown member names and i am able to get just **name** but i want to show **editorName** from nested object.I tried with using loadsh, forEach but unable to display.I am new to ngrx.

### Html:

```
<div class="dopdown" *ngFor='let item of items$ |async'>
<a href="">{{item.name}}</a></div
```

### API RESPONSE:

```
[{
"grpId": 1,
"name": "brain editor",
"member": {
    "gif1": {
        "gpId": "gp1",
        "firstName": "Danny",
        "lastName": "Johns",
        "editorName": "Danny-Johns",
        "suffix": "JR.",
        "Add": true
    },
    "gif2": {
        "gpId": "gp2",
        "firstName": "Mary",
        "lastName": "chang",
        "editorName": "Mary-chang",
        "suffix": "JR.",
        "Added": true
    }
},
"numbers": {
    "a01": {
        "numbersId": "a1",
        "numbersShow": "Dnn1093746",
        "numbersTo": ["gf1", "gf4"],
    }
}}]
```

### angular.service.ts

```
  export class NewService {
     private _myUrl = 'http://myJsonApi';
   constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

      getData(): Observable<Idata[]>{
              return this._http.get<Idata[]>(this._myUrl)
              .pipe(
                      tap(data => {}),
                     catch(this.handleError)) }     
   private handleError(err : HttpErrorResponse){   
                 return Observable.throw(err.message);}}
```

### Component.ts:

```
 export class NewClass implements OnInit {
   vm: any = {};
   items$: Observable<Idata[]>

   constructor(private store: store<fromRoot.AppState>) {}

      ngOnInit(): void {
              this.items$ = this.store.select(fromRoot.getNameDrpdwn)
              getData(); 
       }
       getData() {
              this.store.dispatch(new nameAction.LoadNameAction());    
       }}
```

### Model.ts

```
export interface Idata {
              grpId: number;
              name: string;
            member: any;
          editorName: string;
     }
```

Comment: From which object? `gif1` or `gif2`?

Comment: Both objects.It should be like: 

Danny-Johns
Mary-chang

Answer (score 0):

Try this interpolation statement

```
{{ item.member.gif1.firstName }}
```

instead of

```
{{item.name}}
```

**EDIT**

```
<div class="dopdown" *ngFor='let item of items$ | async'>
    <a href="">{{item.member.gif1.editorName}}</a>
    <a href="">{{item.member.gif2.editorName}}</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Why use square bracket notation instead of dot?

Comment: You‘re right. Dot makes more sense here. Corrected it.

Comment: Right.This way it will be name from one object.I want to display editorName from both objects gif1 and gif2

Comment: I edited my answer. You can solve this task with nested ngFor-loops.

Comment: @DiabolicWords  Thanks but this way it is not working. Any idea why is that?

Comment: What‘s the result on the screen? Do you der any errors in the browser console?

Comment: I edited my code again. The problem is, that your items are elements of an array. Here you can use ngFor and iterate through them. However, member is a collection of gif-object. You cannot iterate with ngFor through it. Just pick both entries and link them directly, as shown in my example.

Comment: Yes this way it is working but the problem is when more gif's are added (gif3,gif4). Then it will only display gif1 and gif2. I want something which can display all gif's.

Comment: I saw an example using lodash forEach method but confused in using with Ngrx

Comment: Okay, I maybe found a solution. ng-repeat supports iteration when it comes to collections. Please, try my Edit2.

Comment: No, it didn't worked. Throws error 'TypeError': Cannot read property 'editorName' of undefined.

Comment: Sorry, then I‘m out. Sorry that I couldn‘t help you any further.